# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '2' in 'on clause'

Tags: php, sql, laravel

```
 public function show($id)
{
    return view('admin.Accueil.accueil', [
        'menus' => Menu::where('parent_id' , NULL)->with('sousMenu')->get(),
        'categories' => DB::table('menus')
            ->join('contents', 'contents.menu_id',  $id)
            ->select('contents.title', 'menus.title As M_title' )
            ->get()
    ] );
}
```

This is the query executed
I need to remove the backticks around the value.

```
select 
    `contents`.`title`, 
    `menus`.`title` as `M_title` 
from 
    `menus` 
inner join `contents` on `contents`.`menu_id` = `2`
```

Comment: Hi. Dont you think your join statement should be something like `->join('contents', 'contents.menu_id',  menus.id)` and the output should be `... join contents on contents.menu_id = menus.id`

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a JOIN condition in your SQL. You need to put a join condition.

Suppose you have menu_id column exists in content table. Your SQL should look like

```
select 
    `contents`.`title`, 
    `menus`.`title` as `M_title` 
from 
    `menus` 
inner join `contents` on `menus`.id = `contents`.`menu_id`
where `contents`.`menu_id` = `2`
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a wrong condition in your join query. Your query should be

```
public function show($id)
{
    return view('admin.Accueil.accueil', [
        'menus' => Menu::where('parent_id' , NULL)->with('sousMenu')->get(),
        'categories' => DB::table('menus')
            ->join('contents', 'contents.menu_id', 'menus.id')
            ->select('contents.title', 'menus.title As M_title' )
            ->where('menus.id',$id)
            ->get()
    ] );
}
```